# how to crop svg image with imagick in php?

Tags: php, svg, imagick

I have SVG images, with lots of white space on the right side and at the bottom.  How do I crop the image (given a fixed size, all images are going to be of same size) using PHP and imagick, and save them back to the same files?

Comment: You can use the PHP library [contao/imagine-svg](https://github.com/contao/imagine-svg) to crop and resize SVG images.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need imagick for this at all. Since SVG is an XML-format you can load the document into a DOMDocument object and change the width and height attributes on the svg tag.

Here's an example (the svg file is borrowed from [jenkov.com](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-transformation.html)) :

```
<?php
$svg = <<< EOF
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <rect x="50" y="50" height="110" width="110"
          style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #ccccff"
          transform="translate(30) rotate(45 50 50)"
            >
    </rect>
    <text x="70" y="100"
          transform="translate(30) rotate(45 50 50)"
    >Hello World</text>
</svg>
EOF;

$myWidth = 100;
$myHeight = 150;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($svg);
$svg = $dom->getElementsByTagName('svg');
$svg->item(0)->setAttribute('width', $myWidth);
$svg->item(0)->setAttribute('height', $myHeight);

print $dom->saveXML($svg->item(0))."\n";
```

Comment: I'd have thought changing the image dimensions, rather than graphic element dimensions, would just do a crop. I should be interested to know myself!

Comment: The default width and height on SVG files is 100% and the canvas' 0,0 point is in the top left corner. Unless the objects within the files are created with relative sizes setting a smaller canvas size should crop the bottom and right whitespace from the files.

Comment: @halfer, I see I missed one word in my answer, the resize should of course only be applied to the <svg> tag and thereby resize only the image dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to add a (tightly fitting) viewBox to your svg files, and then rasterize them with imagemagick.

Some options for doing the first step:

- [SVG Cleaner](http://libregraphicsworld.org/blog/entry/introducing-svg-cleaner)
- [SVG Scour](http://www.codedread.com/scour/)

Comment: The link for SVG Cleaner links to some spam websites. I don't know if you can find a new link to the original program?